# Detect Attached Profiler

Tags: c#, .net, windows, profiling

I know you can determine if a debugger is attached by using `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached`, but is there a way of determining if a profiler is attached?

My profiler can't trace tasks through the threadpool so I want to automaticly disable parallelism when profiling.

Comment: Which profiler do you use?  I don't know of a general solutions but there may be a profiler-specific one.

Comment: I'm using SlimTune at the moment because it was super simple to set up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the standard profiler interface, an environment variable needs to be set.

I guess you can just check this via the `Environment` class.

The variable is called `COR_ENABLE_PROFILING` and if enabled, will be set to `1`.

Answer (score 1):

Debugger.IsAttached code is included whether debug or release build. And a debugger can be attached to release builds to.

Hence  `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached` would return False if no debugger (or profiler) is attached.

Note: I am not sure about SlimTune but Profilers you tend to attach to the process: [How to: Attach and Detach the Profiler to Running Processes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182384.aspx)

Comment: That's nice... but doesn't answer my question. Debugger.IsAttached responds to the debugger not profiler.

Comment: +1 np's Leppie's looks good. So to confirm `Debugger.IsAttached` has no bearing when SimeTune is profiling? Not sure why you would want to profile with out parallelism - the results would be skewed, like profiling in debug-mode

Comment: You are correct - while SlimTune is sampling `IsAttached` returns false. My use of parallelism has mostly independent tasks and subtasks running on the threadpool - I like being able to see the strict hierarchy of function calls.

Answer (score 1):

For those interested, it seems you can detect if your process is being profiled by the Diagnostics Hub of Visual Studio (at least in Visual Studio 2017) by checking the existence of the `DIAGHUB_SESSION_ID` environment variable.